# Partial Class Instance Initialization Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, constructor, nullreferenceexception, partial-classes, custom-type

I have a service with reference code below:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:customer")]
public partial class Receipt : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private int counternoField;

    private double activekwhField;


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("counter-no")]
    public int counterno {
        get {
            return this.counternoField;
        }
        set {
            this.counternoField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("counterno");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("active-km")]
    public double activekm {
        get {
            return this.activekm Field;
        }
        set {
            this.activekmField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("activekm");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:customer")]
public partial class ArrayOfReceipt : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private Receipt[] itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public Receipt[] item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("item");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And, when I want to create an instance of "ArrayOfReceipt" or set a value, or access it, I always encounter the same problem: System.NullReferenceException.
This is the code when I try to create:

```
var prev_Cons = new myService.Receipt();
prev_Cons.counterno = 1;
prev_Cons.activekm = 3265;
myService.ArrayOfReceipt prev_ConsArr = new myService.ArrayOfReceipt();
prev_ConsArr.item.SetValue(prev_Cons, 0);
```

Unfortunatelly, prev_ConsArr.item is always null, and I cannot initialize it. Please show me a way to initialize and set some value to this object. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your code is written, you can initialize prev_ConsArr.item like this:

```
prev_ConsArr.item = new Receipt[3];
```

That would create a new ArrayOfReceipt that could hold three Receipt objects.  You could also create a constructor for your ArrayOfReceipt class that initializes `item`.  Either of these methods will eliminate your NullReferenceException

Looking at the way you are using your ArrayOfReceipt class, you may want to consider changing the type of `item` to `List<Receipt>`.  That would make it easier to change the number of Receipt classes you are storing.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you may also want to create an `AddReceipt` method in ArrayOfReceipts and move your`PropertyChanged` event to that method.  Right now, the `PropertyChanged` event will only fire when  your `ArrayOfReceipts` class overwrites its array of `Receipts`.